# app keeps crashing on launch no errors showing iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, segue, pfquery

my app keeps launching on start up and i'm not sure why can you guys please help! the app works perfectly in the simulator but when i try it on devices the app crashes on launch and in my project there are no errors.

```
@implementation InboxViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
         // NSLog(@"current user: %@", currentUser.username);
    } else {
         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(retrieveMessages) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];

    if ([PFUser currentUser]) {
    [self retrieveMessages];
    } else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showLogin" sender:self];
    }
}
```

retrieveMessage method:

```
- (void)retrieveMessages
{
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Messages"];
    [query whereKey:@"recipientIds" equalTo:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId]];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error){
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"error %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);

        } else {
            self.messages = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }

        if ([self.refreshControl isRefreshing]) {
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        }

    }];
}
```

crash log:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x1829c02d8 0x1945900e4 0x1829c0218 0x100103a80 0x100107f70 0x1001580bc 0x1000c95e4 0x1877e3364 0x1877e4650 0x188b6b594 0x182977a54 0x1829779b4 0x182975934 0x1828a12d4 0x18c1cf6fc 0x18749ef40 0x1000c9c28 0x194c3aa08)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d53270 0x194d38000 + 111216
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194df116c 0x194dec000 + 20844
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000194ccab14 0x194c68000 + 404244
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193d5d414 0x193d5c000 + 5140
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193d7cb88 0x193d5c000 + 134024
5   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001945903bc 0x194588000 + 33724
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193d79bb0 0x193d5c000 + 121776
7   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000193d79474 0x193d5c000 + 119924
8   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000194590200 0x194588000 + 33280
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001829c0214 0x182898000 + 1212948
14  UIKit                           0x00000001877e3360 0x187428000 + 3912544
15  UIKit                           0x00000001877e464c 0x187428000 + 3917388
16  AppSupport                      0x0000000188b6b590 0x188b68000 + 13712
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182977a50 0x182898000 + 916048
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001829779b0 0x182898000 + 915888
19  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000182975930 0x182898000 + 907568
20  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001828a12d0 0x182898000 + 37584
21  GraphicsServices                0x000000018c1cf6f8 0x18c1c4000 + 46840
22  UIKit                           0x000000018749ef3c 0x187428000 + 
24  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000194c3aa04 0x194c38000 + 10756

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d38c24 0x194d38000 + 3108
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194c1de6c 0x194c0c000 + 73324
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000194c0f998 0x194c0c000 + 14744

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000194d53c78 0x194d38000 + 113784
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194ded2d8 0x194dec000 + 4824
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000194deceec 0x194dec000 + 3820

Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.parse.reachability
Thread 4 name:  Dispatch queue: com.parse.PFCommandCache.processing
Thread 7 name:  Dispatch queue: com.parse.PFCommandCache.processing
Thread 11 name:  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x1740329a0 :: NSOperation 0x1740e8200 (QOS: LEGACY)
```

it goes on for a while could it be due to notifications in app delegate did finish launching with options method:

```
 UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Could it be due to retrieving the messages from parse could that be causing an issue? See last few thread messages in crash log?

Comment: Try get crash log from device and add it to your question.

Comment: did you try deleting the app and re running or clearing out derived data?

Comment: Yes I have tried everything and I'm not sure why it's not working

Comment: Have you tried to debug with breakpoints to see where actually your code is crashing?

Comment: It's not crashing In Xcode it only crashes on devices

Comment: It might be because your app is either taking too much memory or cpu utlization, Can you try putting your code in background thread , for example this one    [self retrieveMessages];

Comment: I'm sure it's none of those as the size is less than 10mb

Comment: what iOS version is your device? and what iOS version are you running in simulator?

Comment: It's 8.4 and it's running on both device and simulator

Comment: In this case, only symbolicating the crash log can help. Try these instructions. https://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/symbolicating-your-ios-crash-reports/

Comment: Could it be due to how I'm getting the messages back from parse

Comment: @smithyy without symbolication it is hard to say where is a problem, but it looks like UIKit not ParseKit.

Comment: Try removing `[self.tableView reloadData];` to rule out problems with the UI and add a breakpoint in its place.

Comment: @RyanKreager sounds like a good idea will try it

Comment: @RyanKreager the messages dont load if thats not there

Comment: But it doesn't  crash either- which means it's a UI problem :-) Can you post your tableView code?

Comment: could it be due to notifications see above in questions

Comment: see the console output of your device - can easily be seen in xcode organizer. It shows asserts, exceptions, NSLogs... which crash report doesnt